# Django: Security of post api without any authentication

Tags: django

I am creating api end points using django for my android mobile app.

I have a

```
signup POST api
login POST api and 
notification token POST api
```

All these views will not need any token based authentication. I am afraid someknow knows the api they can misuse them.

How to protect them

Comment: What kind of misuse are you worried about? For a mobile app, you are probably required to use https encryption for your api. The drf docs explain how you can implement throttling policies. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signup can be restricted by using a captcha...
Most bots would not be able to use it, and it would be annoying for some human to misuse it.
The login would take credentials and can be spammed but only few would actually login...
This should return a token which can be used to access all other APIs.

Also if you're worried about too many requests, you can throttle them.

Comment: `This should return a token which can be used to access all other APIs.` SO you mean i have to create a unique token for each app and have to verify at backend. 

Also I dont know the expiry time for the  notification token which i have to save in the DJAngo backend in that case should i still create a jwt token with expiration time. or jwt token without expiration.

Comment: If your APIs need to be restricted to authenticated users, you would need the token (or any other way of authentication), else there is no need of signup & login. You can set an arbitrary expiration like 2 weeks and renew it each time it is used. You can have a cronjob to delete expired tokens